# how to calculate probability that a service exceeds x hours

Tags: probability

Can some one help me with the workings for part a and b, i have the answers (0.223 and 0.166), but can't  figure out how it was calculated...

If the time taken to service a truck is exponentially distributed with an average of 5 hours.
(a) Calculate the probability that a service exceeds 7.5 hours;
(b) If one particular truck takes more than 6 hours to service, what is the probability that the service takes at least 10 hours?

Thank you

Comment: On this site, you are expected to show what you have tried so far. Please find the CDF of the appropriate exponential distribution and show how to use it to get the answer to (a).  _Please edit that into your question,_ to keep it from being (further) down-voted and possible closed. // Normally, I would not have answered a question with no evidence of what you have tried. However, there is a difficulty with your answer to part (b), and I'm pretty sure that's the main reason for asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the CDF of the appropriate exponential distribution.
I show answers using R, where `pexp` is an exponential CDF and the parameter is the rate $\lambda = 1/\mu$.

(a) $P(X > 7.5) = 1 - P(X \le 7.5) = 1 - F_X(7.5) =  0.2231302.$

```
1- pexp(7.5, 1/5)
[1] 0.2231302
```

(b) As stated, you're asking for $$P(X > 10|X  > 6) = P(X > 4) = 1 - P(X\le 4) = 0.449329.$$
Use the [***no-memory property***](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3845489/problem-on-exponential-distribution-and-conditional-probability). Knowing that the truck is not finished by 4 hours, we want the probability of more than 4 *additional* hours.

```
1- pexp(4, 1/5)
[1] 0.449329
```

Either I misunderstand the problem or you have the wrong answer. Your answer is for the probability that it will take between 6 and 10 hours to service the truck
(with no advance knowledge it will take more than 6 hours.)
$$P(6 < X \le 10) =  P(X \le 10) - P(X \le 6)\\ = F_X(10) - F_X(6) = 0.1658589.$$

```
diff(pexp(c(6,10), 1/5))
[1] 0.1658589
```

I can't say whether the person who got this answer was confused, or whether something
got lost translating the original problem into English.